# completely baffled by async / await

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

OK so I'm working on a little MP3 player app. It uses a DataSet to hold MP3 file info. This question is about how to load my DataSet asynchronously. I have been reading around quite a bit, and tried a bunch of stuff, but I just don't get it. All I want to do is take a long-running process DataSet fill process and make it asynchronous.

In The Beginning, I had a method of my DataSet (LoadMusic) that looked like this:

```
public partial class dsMusicPlayer
{
    public void LoadMusic()
    { ... }
}
```

It scans the MP3 files in a directory structure and fills the DataSet with the file info (title, artist, album, etc). It works, but takes a minute or so to run, and blocks the UI naturally. So, perfect candidate for being made asynchronous. I re-wrote my load method like this (without changing implementation otherwise):

```
public async void LoadMusicAsync()
{
}
```

I knew it wouldn't be that simple, but I'm going one step at a time. Sure enough, I get a warning that my async method 'lacks await operators.' All the reading I've done shows "await" being used before a method call, so I refactor the body of my original method out to a dummy private method whose only purpose is to allow the 'await' keyword to be used in the container/public method:

```
public async void LoadMusicAsync()
{
    await LoadMusicInner();
}

private void LoadMusicInner()
{
}
```

Next I see that I can't 'await void.' Fine. I change my private method to

```
private Task LoadMusicInner()
{
}
```

But now I get the error 'not all code paths return a value' -- it makes sense because the return type is Task. And here's the point where I feel stuck. My method was void to begin with because it really doesn't return anything. How should I have done this?

Comment: btw I eventually gave up an used an old-school BackgroundWorker object that I understand, but my question still stands.

Comment: There are numerous articles on async/await basics.

Comment: I read a handful, but couldn't really get anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should look more like this:

```
public async Task LoadMusicAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => this.LoadMusicInner());
}

private void LoadMusicInner()
{
    // Work here..
}
```

Comment: thanks, haven't had a chance to try yet, but will when I get home.

Comment: Most of the time, it shouldn't look like this. Library methods shouldn't use `Task.Run()` just to pretend to be asynchronous.

Comment: @svick async tasks of determinable length are acceptable candidates for `Task.Run`. Starting your own thread is the ultimate best practice but a custom scheduler (that avoids thread pooled threads) will provide the same results. The slimmest solution is TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` - it causes the default scheduler to avoid the threadpool when set. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is to execute some synchronous code on a background thread, then in your calling code, you can do something like:

```
await Task.Run(() => player.LoadMusic());
```

This requires you to make the whole method where you're making this call `async`. If it's not a top-level event handler, then it should be an `async Task` method and its caller should `await` it too, spreading `async` all the way to the top. The top-level event handler then should be `async void` (avoid `async void` pretty much everywhere else).

If you want to make your code truly asynchronous (i.e. not blocking a thread when doing IO), then you need to actually change the implementation of `LoadMusic()` by replacing synchronous calls (like `reader.ReadLine()`) into their asynchronous versions (like `await reader.ReadLineAsync()`).